# Store pointer to Eigen Vector 'segment' without copy?

Tags: c++, eigen

I have an Eigen Vector that I would like to refer to a `segment` at a later time (e.g. pass between functions) instead of modifying immediately.

```
Eigen::Matrix<float, Eigen::Dynamic, 1> vec(10);

// initialize
vec << 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10;
```

I would like to create a pointer to a `segment` that I can refer to later.  The following works but it creates a copy so any changes made to the `segment` are not reflected in the original vector.

```
const int start = 2;
const int end = 8

Eigen::Matrix<float, Eigen::Dynamic, 1> *block = new Eigen::Matrix<float, Eigen::Dynamic, 1>(end - start + 1, 1);
*block = vec.segment(start-1,end-1);
```

How can I keep a reference to the `segment` without copying?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use an [`Eigen::Map`](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1Map.html) to wrap an existing segment of memory without copying. I'm not sure why you're allocating the `*block` object and not just using `block`. Using a `Map` it would look like

```
Eigen::Map<Eigen::VectorXf> block(&vec(start - 1), end - start + 1);
```

You then use the `Map` as you would a normal `VectorXd`, sans resizing and stuff. Simpler yet (at least according to [@ggael](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34299447/store-pointer-to-eigen-vector-segment-without-copy/34303900#comment56362134_34303900)), you can use an [`Eigen:Ref`](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/classEigen_1_1Ref.html) to refer to part of an Eigen object without inducing a copy. For example:

```
void times2(Eigen::Ref< Eigen::VectorXf> rf)
{
    rf *= 2.f;
}
int main()
{

    Eigen::Matrix<float, Eigen::Dynamic, 1> vec(10);

    // initialize
    vec << 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10;

    const int start = 2;
    const int end = 8;

    // This would work as well
    //Eigen::Map<Eigen::VectorXf> block(&vec(start - 1), end - start + 1);

    Eigen::Ref<Eigen::VectorXf> block = vec.segment(start, end - start + 1);

    std::cout << block << "\n\n";

    times2(block);

    std::cout << vec << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

P.S. I think you're misusing the `segment` function. It takes a beginning position an the number of elements, i.e. `(start, end-start+1)`.

Comment: No need for `Map` here, you can directly store a segment as a `Ref`: `Ref<VectorXf> block = vec.segment(start,length);`

Comment: @ggael Is there any advantage/disadvantage to either, or are they essentially the same?

Comment: internally they amount to the same, but using a `Ref` is much simpler for the end-user.

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to return a `Map` of a submatrix too?  I have functions that accept a `Map` object but don't expect a `Ref`.